# Check to see if array contains string or int and complete if/else statement

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, integer, block

Please help to explain what is needed in my code to decipher if the array contains an integer, if it does I need to add 1 to it and if doesn't if will just display the string or symbol.

I have left #notes where my brain stopped working

```
# possible arrays
# array = [1, "two", :three]
# array = [1, 2, 3]
class Array
  def new_map
    result = []
    self.each do |item|
      yield(item)
      if  #check to see if item is an integer
        result << item + 1
      else
        # add string to result array 
      end
    end
    result
  end
end
```

Here is the Rspec test:

```
describe "Array" do
  describe "new_map" do
    it "should not call map" do
      a = [1, 2, 3]
      a.stub(:map) { '' }
      a.new_map { |i| i + 1 }.should eq([2, 3, 4])
    end
    it "should map any object" do
      a = [1, "two", :three]
      a.new_map { |i| i.class }.should eq([Fixnum, String, Symbol])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if item.is_a? Integer
   result << item + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def new_map
    result = []
    self.each do |item|
      yield(item)
      if item.class == Integer #  or if item.is_a? Integer
      result << item + 1
      else
      # add string to result array 
      end
    end
    result
  end
end
```

example:

```
=> 1.is_a? Integer
=> true
=> "1".is_a? Integer
=> false
=> 1_000_000.is_a? Integer
=> true
=> 1_000_000.class
=> Fixnum
=> 1_000_000.is_a? Integer
=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Array
  def new_map
    map do |item|
      yield(item)
    end
  end
end
```

Actually you first spec does not make sense. You yield `i + 1` to the block. This must fail if `ì` is not a `Fixnum`. You must not check if something is an `Integer` in your method, but in the block. This should work:

```
describe "Array" do
  describe "new_map" do
    it "should not call map" do
      a = [1, 2, 3]
      a.new_map { |i| (i.is_a?(Integer) ? i + 1 : i) }.should eq([2, 3, 4])
    end

    it "should map any object" do
      a = [1, "two", :three]
      a.new_map { |i| i.class }.should eq([Fixnum, String, Symbol])
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def new_map
    result = []
    self.each do |item|
      result << yield(item)
    end
    result
  end
end
```

And both your tests pass, don't check object's class unnecessarily, trust duck typing.